# How to get previous/ current quarter and year start and end dates for a year that starts on a date different from 01/01 in Java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am trying to implement a way to return the following:

- current quarter date
- previous quarter date
- current year
- previous year

I was able to figure out how to do it for a typical year starting on 01/01 with the following:

```
      //Current quarter start and end date
      aCalendar.setTime(this.startdate);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, aCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) / 3 * 3);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    this.quarterStartDate = aCalendar.getTime();

    aCalendar.setTime(this.startdate);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, aCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) / 3 * 3 + 2);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, aCalendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    this.quarterEndDate = aCalendar.getTime();
    if (this.quarterEndDate.getTime() > currentCalendar.getTimeInMillis())
        this.quarterEndDate = currentCalendar.getTime();

    // previous quarter
    aCalendar.setTime(this.startdate);
    aCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, aCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) / 3 * 3 + 2);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, aCalendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    this.previousQuarterEndDate = aCalendar.getTime();

    aCalendar.setTime(this.startdate);
    aCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, aCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) / 3 * 3);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    this.previousQuarterStartDate = aCalendar.getTime();

    // current year
    aCalendar.setTime(this.startdate);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); 
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31); 
    this.currentYearEndDate = aCalendar.getTime();

    if (this.currentYearEndDate.getTime() > currentCalendar.getTimeInMillis())
        this.currentYearEndDate = currentCalendar.getTime();

    aCalendar.setTime(this.startdate);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0); 
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); 
    this.currentYearStartDate = aCalendar.getTime();

    // previous year
    aCalendar.setTime(this.currentYearEndDate);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, aCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); // 
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31); 
    this.previousYearEndDate = aCalendar.getTime();

    aCalendar.setTime(this.currentYearStartDate);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, aCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1);
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0); // 
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); 
    this.previousYearStartDate = aCalendar.getTime();
```

However, what I am trying to solve is if the year starts on a different day for example 3/01/2018 than the Quarters would be

> ```
> **Q1** = 03/01/2018 -05/31/2018
> **Q2** = 06/01/2018- 08/30/2018
> **Q3** = 09/01/2018 - 11/30/2018
> **Q4** = 12/01/2018 - 02/28/2019
> ```

**MY QUESTION**  is how can I return the current/previous quarter and year start and end date. For example lets say today's date is 10/19/2018
than the following should be returned:

- current quarter: Start_Date = 9/1/2018      End_Date = 10/19/2018
- previous quarter: Start_Date = 6/1/2018     End_Date = 8/30/2018
- Current year: Start_Date =  3/1/2018        End_Date = 10/19/2018
- previous year:Start_Date =  3/12017         End_Date = 2/28/2018

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? I fail to see how any of the three answers to the linked question can take into account that the year may not begin on January 1. @mocodes, have you got an opinion?

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
    final Month yearStart = Month.MARCH;
    final int yearStartValue = yearStart.getValue();

    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.OCTOBER, 19);

    // Current quarter start and end date
    // First find 0-based month witin quarter; 0, 1 or 2 
    int monthInQuarter = (currentDate.getMonthValue() + 12 - yearStartValue) % 3;
    LocalDate currentQuarterStart
            = currentDate.withDayOfMonth(1).minusMonths(monthInQuarter);
    LocalDate currentQuarterEndInclusive
            = currentQuarterStart.plusMonths(3).minusDays(1);
    System.out.println("Current quarter:  " + currentQuarterStart
            + " through " + currentQuarterEndInclusive);

    // previous quarter
    LocalDate previousQuarterStart = currentQuarterStart.minusMonths(3);
    LocalDate previousQuarterEndInclusive = currentQuarterStart.minusDays(1);
    System.out.println("Previous quarter: " + previousQuarterStart
            + " through " + previousQuarterEndInclusive);

    // current year
    // Find 0-based month in year
    int monthInYear = (currentDate.getMonthValue() + 12 - yearStartValue) % 12;
    LocalDate currentYearStart
            = currentDate.withDayOfMonth(1).minusMonths(monthInYear);
    LocalDate currentYearEndInclusive
            = currentYearStart.plusYears(1).minusDays(1);
    System.out.println("Current year:     " + currentYearStart
            + " through " + currentYearEndInclusive);

    // previous year
    LocalDate previousYearStart = currentYearStart.minusYears(1);
    LocalDate previousYearEndInclusive = currentYearStart.minusDays(1);
    System.out.println("Previous year:    " + previousYearStart
            + " through " + previousYearEndInclusive);
```

With a year starting March 1 and a current date of October 19, 2018, the above snippet outputs:

> ```
> Current quarter:  2018-09-01 through 2018-11-30
> Previous quarter: 2018-06-01 through 2018-08-31
> Current year:     2018-03-01 through 2019-02-28
> Previous year:    2017-03-01 through 2018-02-28
> ```

You shouldn’t want to use the `Calendar` class. It has several design issues and is long outdated. Instead I use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Contrary to a `Calendar` a `LocalDate` represents a date without time of day and without time zone, so it is what we need here.

Since time intervals are usually half-open — from start inclusive to end exclusive — I have added `Inclusive` to the names of the end date variables to make clear that we are using closed intervals here.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.